# Using openCV in ROS to stream images from AR-Drone

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I would like to use openCV to process images from an **AR-Drone 2.0**. I would like the images to be streamed into openCV from the AR-Drone 2.0 but I do not know how to set this up. I am using the ardrone_autonomy to interface the Ardrone 2.0 with ROS and that is setup already. I noticed a section on cameras link:[text](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy#cameras) however it does not talk about openCV support with this image stream (I think it just shows an image feed to the computer).

Any links to this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73558/using-opencv-in-ros-to-stream-images-from-ar-drone/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[cv_bridge](http://ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge) can convert images to opencv types. The cv_bridge tutorials have examples in python and C++ of subscribing to images and converting them for use with opencv.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-18**:
Brilliant. Thank you Dan :)

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-18**:
Just to check with you, should I download the latest stable release of openCV? Does the version matter in terms of working well with cv_bridge?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-08-18**:
If you're using ROS groovy or earlier, you should use the version packaged with ROS. Hydro or later, I'm not sure.

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-18**:
I am using ROS Fuerte. When you say a version packaged with ROS, do you mean this:http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=fuerte&name=vision_opencv

I am slightly confused how to install this if the above is what I should have.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-08-18**:
Yep, that's right. You can install it with apt-get install ros-fuerte-vision-opencv if you're using Ubuntu.

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-18**:
I noticed that I already had vision_opencv within \opt\ros\fuerte\stacks ! Is it best to download something like eclipse? Also, how can I check what version for opencv this is?